# the questions about quartz.net ' trigger

Tags: triggers, quartz.net

i know ,in quartz.net ,change a old trigger like  below,

```
scheduler.RescheduleJob(oldname,oldgroup,newtrigger);
```

it need have not the same name with old trigger name,

but i need to change trigger with the same trigger name,is there anyway to solve?

Answer (score 3):

You can also delete the trigger using `scheduler.UnscheduleJob(triggerName, groupName)`and then schedule the job again.

Comment: thanks,shoud i pause the job or trigger before using `UnscheduleJob(triggerName, groupName)`?